# Scheduling local notification for a specific date and repeat yearly

Tags: codenameone

I want to use the local notification in my app where i want to send birthday message for the user every year.

1)How can i schedule notification in a specific date and time? Here using Display.getInstance().scheduleLocalNotification, I can set time to schedule the notification but how can i set the specific date and time?

2)There is REPEAT_NONE, minute,hour,day,week but is there Repeat_Year as well?

3)Is there any specific use for override method of localNotification ie. localNotificationReceived()? I have System.out and Dialog.show methods but both doesnt show when the notification shows up.

```
public class LocalNotificationTest implements LocalNotificationCallback {
    public void noti(){
        LocalNotification n = new LocalNotification();
        n.setAlertBody("body");
        n.setAlertTitle("title");
        n.setId("id");
        Display.getInstance().scheduleLocalNotification(n, System.currentTimeMillis() + 10 * 1000, LocalNotification.REPEAT_NONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void localNotificationReceived(String notificationId) {
         System.out.println("Received local notification "+notificationId+" in callback localNotificationReceived");
         Dialog.show("noti", "checking notifications", "ok", null);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could set the repeat to week, for example, and in the callback increment a counter until the 52nd occurrence when you would actually notify the user, ignoring the first 51 instances of getting notifications.

The counter value can be stored in Preferences for persistence.

Comment: That won't work because dates don't land on the same date since 365 / 7 is not an integer. It would need to use repeat day for this to work, I'm not sure why repeat year isn't there though.

Comment: Alternatively you can just set 120 notifications for all the future years instead of a repeat

Comment: thankyou both.. what is the purpose of localNotificationReceived() method here, i have Dialog.show() inside it but the dialog doesnt show up when notification is triggered, why is that?

Comment: Using repeat day would be off on leap years, make sure if you use that to account for them.

Comment: hello i have one more question. Does local notification only works if the app is in the background? Won't it work if the app is closed? I have tested in devices, the notification appears only if the app is minimized (in background)